# ¿Como puedo conectar desde un mismo archivo a 2 bases de datos con php?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 bases de datos, una es login que tiene una tabla llamada users, ahí es donde guardo la información de id, usuario y contraseña, después tengo otra base que es example (es de prueba esta base por eso el nombre, solo ignórenlo) ahí tengo una tabla llamada ejemplo, ahí es donde guardo una información que es id y titulo.

Acá dejo como es mejor en un "esquema":

Base de datos donde guardo la información del login

login ---| users | id, user, password

Después tengo la otra base de ejemplo

example ---| ejemplo | id, tittle

Como puedo hacer para que desde un archivo de Home que es donde me redirecciona una vez que se validan los datos de inicio de sección, para que desde el archivo de php de home, que esta conectada a la base de login, para conectarla también con la de example, así de esa manera pueda comprobar lo del login, y luego pueda mediante un input enviar datos a la tabla de ejemplo de la base de example.

No se si me hago entender.

!+ mas info:

Tengo mi archivo de conneccion asi:

db_connect.php

Codigo:

````
$sname = "name";
$unmae = "name";
$password = "name";

$db_name = "login";

$conn = mysqli_connect($sname, $unmae, $password, $db_name);

if(!$conn){
    echo "Connection failed!";
}

?> ```
````

Comment: ¿Por que no generas las tablas de `ejemplo` y `users` bajo una única base de datos con el nombre del proyecto? Tiene más sentido de esta manera ya que solo necesitarás una única conexión a la base de datos y obtendrás acceso a todas las tablas necesarias.

Comment: Repite lo que ya sabes pero con los datos de la otra, cambiando ligeramente los nombres, para crearte otro handle de base de datos. Usa, por ejemplo, $sname_example, $unmae_example, $password_example, $db_name_example, y finalmente $conn_example.  Y luego, cuando hagas consultas, usa el handle que corresponda segun la tabla que estes consultando.

Answer (score 0):

quiza te convenga utilizar usa sola base de datos, pero si necesitas usar dos te muestro citando tu codigo podes hacerlo

```
<?php
$sname = "name";
$unmae = "name";
$password = "name";
$db_name = "login";


$sname2 = "name";
$unmae2 = "name";
$password2 = "name";
$db_name2 = "login";

$conn = mysqli_connect($sname, $unmae, $password, $db_name);

$conn2 = mysqli_connect($sname2, $unmae2, $password2, $db_name2);

if(!$conn || !$conn2){
    echo "Connection failed!";
}

?>
```